# $.link jsrender doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

In console shows this error message

> Uncaught TypeError: $.link is not a function at 6.html:17.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="jsrender-master/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jsViews.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <label><input data-link="show" type="checkbox"/> Show</label>
    <div data-link="{if show tmpl='show this'}{else tmpl='no show'}"></div>

    <script>
    $.link(true, "body", {show: true});


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include these three files, otherwise it can't work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.90/jsrender.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jquery.observable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jquery.views.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively you can replace jsrender.js with a single file, jsviews.js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsviews/0.9.90/jsviews.min.js"></script>
```

See http://www.jsviews.com/#download